# singleton="false" is no longer supported in Spring 4.3.8. Need solution

Tags: spring, spring-bean

We are upgrading from Spring 3.2.4 to Spring 4.3.8 in which singleton="false" is no longer supported. What is the way to set singleton 'false' in Spring 4.3.8?
If singeton="false" then does it means that spring bean scope has become "Prototype"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use @Scope for specifying prototype bean.

Example:

```
@Bean @Scope("prototype")
public Person personPrototype() {
    return new Person();
}
```

for further reading follow [link](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, `singleton=false` was kept for some compatibility reasons, also indicated in some older [docs, eg 3.0.0.M3](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html):

> `<bean id="accountService" class="com.foo.DefaultAccountService"/>`
>
> the following is equivalent, though redundant (singleton scope is the default); using spring-beans-2.0.dtd
>   `<bean id="accountService"> class="com.foo.DefaultAccountService" scope="singleton"/>`
>
> **the following is equivalent and preserved for backward compatibility in spring-beans.dtd**
>   `<bean id="accountService"> class="com.foo.DefaultAccountService" singleton="true"/>`

Anyway, the default spring scope is `singleton`, so even when unspecified, but [can be changed to `prototype` (or whatever you need) with](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes):

- XML: `scope="prototype"`
- Java DSL: `@Scope("prototype")` or `@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)`

Answer (score 0):

Correct, scope="prototype" is the direct equivalent of singleton="false".

- The equivalent of singleton="false" is scope="prototype".
- another alternative is to use the annotation @Scope("prototype")
- The equivalent of singleton="true" would be to eliminate this attribute in the spring config, since scope="singleton" would be the default.